# How do I create a method with a Class as an argument?

Tags: java

How do I create a method that accepts a class object as its argument. For example `setLab` method will accept assessment(class) object as its argument, and also create an array that reference to that object(class)

I have something like this but it doesn't seem to work.

```
Assessment[] assessment;

public Ratin()
{
 element = new Assessment[4];
}

public void setLab(Assessment assessment)
{
  assessment.setScore(85);
  element[0] = assessment;
}
```

Comment: `Assessment[] assessment;` should probably be `Assessment[] element;` I guess.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
Assessment[] element;

public Ratin()
{
    element = new Assessment[4];
}

public void setLab(Assessment assessment)
{
    assessment.setScore(85);
    element[0] = assessment;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this doesn't answer the question. It only addresses the incorrect instance array variable name, which nhgrif already pointed out in the comments.

Comment: setLab is doing that already

Comment: Tell us what is wrong with the code I posted?

Comment: As I stated already, you've only addressed one small aspect (which I suspect is probably merely an omission on the OP's part), which has already been stated in the question-comments, and does not ultimately solve the problem the OP has asked for, which is how to pass a Class as an argument to a method. Your code is technically correct, but it is merely an demonstration of what nhgrif said, and is ultimately unnecessary.

Comment: Are you the one to accept the answer or the person that asked the question?

Comment: You seem to be taking it personally; there's no need.

Comment: This does not answer the question in any way and doesn't explain the provided code.

Answer (score 3):

You can look at the `Class` class. That will let you pass a `Class` object as an argument.

With that, you can do all sort of wizardry like get its methods, package name, fields, etc. Have a look at the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html

```
setLab(Class someClass){
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Yup. And they can also do `Class< Assessment>` if they want the specificity.

Comment: @Teeg I am not aware of that. How does that work ? never used `Class` with generics

Comment: Its nothing you wouldn't expect from a generic type; there are methods that will return an object of the generic type, such as [`newInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance()) for example. Its convenient, and you don't have to worry about casting.